# Mimic Sublime's handling of unsaved files in Atom

Tags: sublimetext, atom-editor

`Sublime` has this cool feature where you can create a new file (or modify an existing one) and close the text editor without having to explicitly save the modifications.

Next time the editor is opened, the unsaved modifications will still be there.

Is there a way to mimic this behaviour in [atom](https://atom.io/)?

Comment: That sublime feature is called `hot exit`. Searching in google for that I found people asking for that feature in atom, some of them says that [this package](https://github.com/mpeterson2/save-session) implements this behaviour. I don't use atom so I don't know if it really works, so be careful in order to avoid losing your work.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't do exactly what `Sublime` does, but its close enough. Would you mind posting your cmmt as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for your response so I can post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sublime feature is called `hot exit`. Although atom doesn't has this feature [this package](https://github.com/mpeterson2/save-session) claims to implement it.

Note: I haven't tested it, so I don't know if it really works; be careful in order to avoid losing your work.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is already included in Atom by default now.

- Settings -> Core Settings uncheck `Open Empty Editor on Start`
- Set `Restore Previous Windows on Start` to `Always`.
- Settings -> Packages -> autosave. In package settings check Enabled.

Also, restore will not work in Atom unless at least one Project has been added to the Project pane. You can add anything there. You can just add my Documents folder.